# Evaluate expression in HIVE set statements

Tags: variables, hadoop, set, hive

In my hive queries I set some variables.

However I realized that hive remember the expression rather than the value, for example:

```
set a=1 ;
set b=2 ;
set c= ${hiveconf:a} + ${hiveconf:b} ;
set c ;
-- the command above returns
-- c=1 + 2
```

Why Hive doesn't evaluate the value? Is there any way to set hive so that
`set c ;` would return `c= 3` in my previous example?

Answer (score 3):

Generally at point you are only defining variables in CLI. Evaluation will take place during map reduce run, ex.

```
SELECT ${hiveconf:c} FROM yourTable LIMIT 1;
```

will give you calculated value of c.

Comment: hi @Wawrzyniec, thanks but this is actually not what I was asking (though I realize the question could seem confused). I know it evaluates them during map reduce, I wanted to know if there is some way to force the evaluation before as well, so that I can check the results. Thanks for your help anyway